# How to emulate background-image whilst supporting printing

Tags: html, css

I'm using background-image to crop images to a width of 200px. I don't know the image widths in advance. I want the middle of the image.

```
 .cropped-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 270px;

    /* centered, cropped image */
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

My HTML template looks like this:

```
    <div class="cropped-image" style="background-image: url({{ product.image_thumb_url }})">
    </div>
```

Here's an example of it in action: http://jsfiddle.net/hRSdY/

This works fine, but web browsers don't print background images by default. I can use `list-style-image` to emulate background-image, but I can't crop to the center of the iamge: http://jsfiddle.net/KP7ng/1/.

Is there any way using CSS to crop images horizontally, keeping the images visible during printing?

Comment: the images are of arbitrary dimensions ?

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli they're of arbitrary widths, yes.

Comment: Wilfred, then it cannot be done with only CSS.. it will require some JS to be done..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that with CSS if the images are of arbitrary dimensions..

You would need to use javascript to reposition them once loaded..

---

a **jQuery** implementation would be

```
$(window).load(function(){
    $('.cropped-image img').each(function(){
        var self = $(this);
        self.css({
            marginLeft: (-this.width/2),
            marginTop: (-this.height/2),
            visibility: 'visible' /*set to visible once loaded and repositioned*/
        })
    });
});
```

with an HTML structure of

```
<div class="cropped-image">
   <img src="{{ product.image_thumb_url }}"/>
</div>
```

and CSS

```
.cropped-image {
    width: 200px;
    height: 270px;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.cropped-image img{
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden; /*set to hidden until the page is loaded to avoid moving images*/
}
```

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/3Yg7V/

Comment: If you use a javascript library. Atleast tell the guy which one :) Otherwise use native javascript instead of a library.

Comment: i write "*a **jquery** implementation would be*"

Comment: bolded it for emphasis .. :)

Comment: Thank you :) Missed that. jQuery does suck you know :) Mootools ftw!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?:

http://jsfiddle.net/WPF75/

html:

```
<div class="crop">
<img src="http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_Mzmuwpq3Fpw/SFQ4dKzbD3I/AAAAAAAAANE/ulNUQpbDKI4/s320/fusion-icon.png" />
</div>
```

​css:

```
div.crop {
    height: 80px;
    border: 1px solid red;  
    overflow: hidden;    
}

div.crop img {
    margin-top: -20%;   
}
​
```

Comment: `margin-top: -20%` is relative to the size of the div, not the image. This crops, but not to the center of the image. Here's an extreme example: http://jsfiddle.net/WPF75/1/

Comment: Correct. And most likely it has to be a fixed value instead. The 20% was for illustration purpouses. If you do not know the size of your image to determine what the middle is, you are stuck with the javascript solution mentioned above.